# C++: Explicitly disable aliasing optimizations for pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, alias

In some code I'm working on, I have a few instances of this pattern:

```
Foo *foo = ...;
// do stuff with foo
if (foo->type == ActuallyBar) {
    Bar *bar = reinterpret_cast<Bar*>(foo);
    // do stuff with bar
    if (bar->type == ActuallyQux) {
        Qux *qux = reinterpret_cast<Qux*>(bar);
        // do stuff with qux
    }
}
```

(I know that this is a terrible C++ anti-pattern, e.g. "stupid polymorphism", but it's old code and would require enormous work to overhaul). To make matters worse, there are no guaranteed inheritance chains (e.g. Qux inherits from Bar inherits from Foo might not be guaranteed, but guaranteeing this might be a more realistic refactor -- let me know your thoughts :) )

My question is about aliasing. At `do stuff with qux`, the pointers `qux` and `bar` point to the same object. I know this is dangerous in C++, because these two pointers point to different types.

However, I will not need to use the variable `bar` more at this point (`qux` is enough).

Is there a good way to disable any aliasing assumptions about these two pointers?

One idea I had was to do

```
union {
    Foo *foo;
    Bar *bar;
    Qux *qux;
} all;
all.foo = ...;
// do stuff with foo
if (all.foo->type == ActuallyBar) {
    all.bar = reinterpret_cast<Bar*>(all.foo);
    // do stuff with bar
    if (all.bar->type == ActuallyQux) {
        all.qux = reinterpret_cast<Qux*>(all.bar);
        // do stuff with qux
    }
}
```

but I'm not sure this would work.

Thanks for any advice! And sorry for summoning demons with this terrible anti-pattern!

Comment: If *"Qux inherits from Bar inherits from Foo might not be guaranteed"* then this could be a straight shot at the leg.

Comment: Replace with `dynamic_cast` and also test the result of the cast.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` is not allowed because there are no virtual functions in these types. I get a compiler error from that: `error C2683: 'dynamic_cast': 'Foo' is not a polymorphic type?`

Comment: You SHOULD at the very least have a virtual destructor if you have inheritance!

Comment: reinterpret_cast is not meant to work in a class hierarchy, and a class hierarchy with no virtual functions makes no sense. That codebsse is broken by design.

Comment: @VTT dynamic_cast never causes UB.

Comment: @n.m. `dynamic_cast` can produce UB in some situation when invoked during object construction and destruction. But `dynamic_cast` can not be used in this case anyway since these classes are not guaranteed to be in the same inheritance chain.

Comment: @VTT Yes I forgot about the case of object construction, or if the pointer doesn't point to a valid object. But in other cases it's perfectly safe to use dynamic_cast even if the two classes are unrelated.

Comment: It's just possible `std::launder` could help you. But you really aren't in a good place.

Comment: With the `union`, there is no need to reassign `all.bar` and `all.qux`, you can directly use them.

Answer (score 0):

You could break the code in different translation unit and disable link time optimization:

`file.cpp`

```
Foo *foo = ...;

// do stuff with foo
if (foo->type == ActuallyBar) 
  do_stuff_with_bar(reinterpret_cast<Bar*>(foo));
```

`file2.cpp`

```
void do_stuff_with_bar(Bar* bar){
  //...
  if (bar->type == ActuallyQux)
    do_stuff_with_qux(reinterpret_cast<Qux*>(bar);
}
```

`file3.cpp ...`

This may make your code less efficient but at least it will do what was intended.

Answer (score 0):

For Gcc style compilerrs (like gcc and clang) you can use the -fno-strict-aliasing option